# Implementing session-like storage in python application

Tags: python, authentication

I will keep it short.

Can someone please point me in the right direction in:

> How to authenticate users in native applications written in Python?

I know in web there are `sessions`, but I can't think of a way to implement authentication, that will 'live' for some time and on expiry I can logout the user?

**EDIT:**

I am referring to desktop type of apps, I am fairly happy with the implementation for Web based development in Twisted

***EDIT 2***
The application I am thinking about will not authenticate against a server, but a self-contained application, an example the idea is a Cash Register/Point of Sale (my idea is kinda different, but parts of the functionality is the same), in which I need to authenticate the cashier, so I can log the transactions processed by him/her, print name on receipt and etc. All will be based in one single machine, no server communication or anything

Comment: Depends on web framework, in Flask http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions, just read the documentation for your framework of choice.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I was not referring to web programming, rather I am looking for implementation/approaches/techniques in native desktop applications

Comment: Please elaborate. What kind of application? Authenticate against what? Are you talking about a ‘thick client’ kind of app talking to your server?

Comment: Please see my second edit for more details @VasiliyFaronov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not entirely clear what kind of security you are expecting.

*In general*, if the end user has physical access to the machine and a screwdriver, you’re pretty much screwed—they can do whatever they want on that machine.

If you take hardware security as a given, but want to ensure software security, then you’re going to have to do *server communication* within the machine’s boundaries. You have to separate the server and the client, and run the server in a security context that is inaccessible to the user. The server will then do both the authentication and whatever operations need authentication (printing out receipts etc.). For example, under a Unix-like OS, you would run a daemon under a dedicated system user or under `root`; on Windows, you would have a system service running as `LOCAL SERVICE` or whatever that’s called. In this way, the operating system’s built-in security features will ensure (given proper maintenance, like timely application of security hotfixes) that the user cannot influence the behavior of the software that does the sensitive operations. The protocol between the client and the server can be anything, and you can do authentication in much the same way as in HTTP—indeed, you may even use HTTP itself.

Finally, if you’re certain that your users will not be tampering with your system at all—e.g. because they lack the technical skills, or are being watched by CCTV cameras—you can forget all that stuff and go with Puciek’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be very confused and fixated on "sessions" for some reasons, maybe because your background is in the web apps?

Any-who you don't need "sessions" because with desktop application you have no trouble telling who is using the software without needing some elaborate tools. You don't need server, you don't need authentication tools, you don't need anything - just store that user within your single application. That is all really - a variable within your application called "user" and maybe some interface at the boot to pick one from available users.
And if you need it to last between boots, just save it in a file and read from it.

Comment: Yes my background is in the web apps, anyhow, how hard-coding the user details in a variable(global?) resolves the problem in case there are two cashiers which can switch at at some dynamic time? (consider flexible shifts) If you can edit and give me an example in sudo-code I will be thankful

Comment: You didn't read my answer very carefully. All you need is just some basic login screen, that is completely unrelated to sessions of any sort.

Comment: So assuming if I had understand correctly:
 Small SQLite DB(for examples sake)
 basic auth screen
 perform check of the uid and password
 true: write data from db entry in to the global variable
 false: try again :D

Can you confirm that this is the basic logic you ware referring to?

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov that is pretty much how log-in works, i mean it is really that basic. Only difference between web and that is that you don't need to worry about sessions, cookies, user switching browsers/ips and all the mess that comes with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was really confused with the auth process as sessions are not in the game any more. I went in to session unavailable panic :D, as how to determinate where the data is to be kept. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Unix, rely on the fact that it's a multi user system. That is, the user has already logged in using his own credentials, so you don't need to do anything, just use its home directory to store the data, taking care to block other users from accessing it by using permissions. You can improve this to provide encryption too. For global application data, you can specify a "manager" user or group, with its own directory, where the application can write.

All this might be possible on Windows systems too.